# An example project for network-programming written in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, filesystems, system

Are there good open-source projects on P2P file-sharing systems or 
distributed file systems written in C/C++ ？

I need a project to start with network-programming.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Boost asio examples on the boost.org are really good one to start.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

Answer (score 3):

[Rasterbar libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent) is probably what **unknown (google)** meant to link to. It is heavily based on Boost, using Boost.Asio for all network code. This is the library used by Halite and many others (but not rTorrent, which used a different library, also called libtorrent).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[libTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/)</strike> [libTorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent) - written in C++, using Boost extensively (and asio mentioned by Mykola). If you want to have a look at a client application using <strike>libTorrent</strike>, then there is rTorrent while for libTorrent - for example [Halite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/halite/) (also using Boost).

EDIT: Thanks to Daniel Wallin for spotting the mixup of the different libTorrents.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be helpful to get familiarize with the concepts.

http://www.flazx.com/category95.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/).